# How to convert base64 to Hex?

Tags: python, encoding, hash, cryptography

I have a script were I save a 64 character hexadecimal ethereum privatekey on an rfid chip:

```
text = input('New data:')
print("Now place your tag to write")

b64 = codecs.encode(codecs.decode(text, 'hex'), 'base64').decode()
print(b64)
reader.write(b64)
print("Written")
```

Which converts my privatekey into a string like this

```
PFed9wmiwVB9vsQtFWJfGGIY2XuLu1uyfdXNc6Sa4KU=
```

Now when I want to convert this back to the privatekey I run into errors with this script in python3:

```
import base64
text = 'PFed9wmiwVB9vsQtFWJfGGIY2XuLu1uyfdXNc6Sa4KU='

dec = base64.b64decode(text).encode('hex')
print(dec)
```

However decoding works fine in python2.

This is the error message:

```
  dec = base64.b64decode(text).encode('hex')
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

I only get this error message in python3.

Comment: hex is a keyword in python so you shouldn't use it as a variable name.

Comment: ok, but converting works, the 2nd part of the code converting it back doesnt work

Comment: can you include the error message you are getting?

Comment: Welcome to SO. *i run into errors* and *doesnt work* are not useful as a problem description. Please be more specific. What error exactly? Reading [ask] will also help.

Comment: i have edited the qquestion and included the error message

Comment: just change `.encode(`'hex')` to `.hex()`  output: *3c579df709a2c1507dbec42d15625f186218d97b8bbb5bb27dd5cd73a49ae0a5*

Comment: @jps legend, thanks